# loop doesn't end while reading from a textfile

Tags: c, string, encryption, file-io

I am typing a very simple C program which reads characters from a file and displays it "encrypted" by replacing each character with the one 3 characters after ([Caesar cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher)).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        FILE *inFile;
        int ch;
        int ch1;

        if (argc!= 2){
                printf("Usage: Code <inputfile> [> Outfile]\n");
                return(-1);
        }

        inFile = fopen(argv[1], "r");
        while ((ch1=toupper(fgetc(inFile)))!='\0') {
                ch=ch1;
                if (ch >=33 && ch <=255)  //exclude special chars
                        ch += 3;
                putchar(ch);
        }
        printf("END\n");
        fclose(inFile);
        return 0;
}
```

I compile it with gcc with `gcc encode.c` and then run `./a textfile`. A line follows with the "encoded" text, then, after 2 seconds, the terminal is filled with garbage, specifically an ascii square. I escape it with Ctrl-C. Obviously the while loop never ends, since I never see the END string. I wondered whether '\0' is the problem and i replaced it with NULL but not only the problem persists, but I also receive a warning during compile.

Comment: `!='\0'` is incorrect. Try `!=EOF`.

Comment: To explain n.m.'s comment: Files are not null-terminated, they are not strings.

Comment: Also, if `ch==254` and you add 3 to it, you're in trouble.

Comment: Ok this does the trick! Which makes me feel silly since I knew `!=EOF` when I was taking classes years ago. BTW do I need the intermediate variable `ch1`? Can the job be performed ok with just `ch`?

Comment: Well, why not try it?

Comment: @n.m. Except for the mention of characters, the input could be binary and the output could be binary. Then there'd be no problem with wrap around (modulo) arithmetic or outputting invalid codepoints.

Comment: @TomBlodget it won't fail, it just will make not too much sense. It's a Caesar cipher for Juno's sake! It's supposed to wrap around